# Fortify + maven exclude xsd files

Tags: jenkins, fortify

I have an issue with running scan with excluding xsd files in fortify SCA.
I am using maven (with fortify plugin) + jenkins.
My POM.xml used by Jenkins:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>pl.bluecode</groupId>
<artifactId>bc</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<properties>

</properties>
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:https://subversion......</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://subversion.....</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
    <url>https://subversion......</url>
</scm>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>common</id>
         <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>!skipCommonProfile</name>
            </property>
         </activation>
        <modules>
            <module>Project1</module>
            <module>Project2</module> 
        </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>profile1</id>
        <modules>
            <module>Project3</module>
            <module>Project4</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-sca-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <failOnSCAError>true</failOnSCAError>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

My Jenkins Maven goals looks like:
1st goal:
com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin:maven-sca-plugin:2.6:clean -Pprofile1

2nd goal:
com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin:maven-sca-plugin:2.6:translate -Pprofile1

3rd goal:
com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin:maven-sca-plugin:2.6:scan -Pprofile1

Unfortunately I can not attach image.

Above configuration is working as expected till now.
Now, I'd like to exclude all XSD files from scan.

How to do it? 
I tried to add -exclude "*.xsd" entry in maven goals:
com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin:maven-sca-plugin:2.6:scan -Pprofile -exclude "*.xsd"

but it doesn't work.

If someone can help we I would be grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in theory the Fortify Maven Plugin supports the exclusion of files, but it doesn't always work as expected.

Now, that being said, ***you are not invoking the exclusion correctly***. Where you built the Fortify Maven Plugin, find the documentation for the `translate` goal, e.g. for me: /Samples/advanced/maven-plugin/target/site/translate-mojo.html#exclude.

There you can find the correct way to invoke exclusion.  On the command line:

```
"-Dfortify.sca.exclude=*.xsd"
```

or in the POM (if you set up the fortify translate job there)

```
<exclude>
 *.xsd
</exclude>
```

Now back to my first point. Sometimes exclusion is more difficult to effect than just by setting the value as *.extension.  You may also need to specify the directory as well, so if the above doesn't work, try also the Fortify special glob parameter "**" which means any recursive subdirectory match. To wit:

```
"-Dfortify.sca.exclude=**/*.xsd"
```

or

```
<exclude>
 **/*.xsd
</exclude>
```

If neither of the above work, then contact Fortify Technical Support.

***Pro tip:*** you can also set this value in Core/config/fortify-sca.properties, where it will affect every invocation of sourceanalyzer on the system. That includes invocations via the maven plugin.

Comment: Unfortulately this solution doesn't work. I tried com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin:maven-sca-plugin:2.6:translate -Pprofile1 -Dfortify.sca.exclude=*.xsd and com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin:maven-sca-plugin:2.6:translate -Pprofile1 -Dfortify.sca.exclude=**/*.xsd

Comment: Hi Dariusz, 
Depending on how you run this command, I believe those `*` characters are going to get interpreted by your shell, and make a mess of your parameters. (If the files in your directory are `a.txt, b.txt` and `c.txt` then `-Dfortify.sca.exclude=*.xsd` becomes `-Dfortify.sca.exclude=a.txt b.txt c.txt.xsd`.
The key is to wrap the parameters in double quotes. So for instance,
     `com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin:maven-sca-plugin:2.6:translate -Pprofile1 "-Dfortify.sca.exclude=**/*.xsd"`

Comment: One other completely different solution you can try is to remove `xsd` from the `com.fortify.sca.DefaultFileTypes` line in `Core/config/fortify-sca.properties`.  If this works, please let me know and I will update my answer more fully.
Unfortunately, this exclusion is not a feature that is implemented consistently.

Comment: Hi Douglas, I have used **com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin:maven-sca-plugin:2.6:translate -Pprofile1 "-Dfortify.sca.exclude=**/*.xsd"** and also **com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin:maven-sca-plugin:2.6:translate -Pprofile1 "-Dfortify.sca.exclude=*.xsd"**. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I have not access to fortify-sca.properties so only thing I can do is use mavan plugin from jentkins. Perhaps excluding xsd files was not implemented yet.